# Test Command Line Program

Tags: bash, testing

So, I have this command line program binary (let's say its named ./prog) that I want to test. I want to use shunit2 as my testing framework. Unfortunately it asks the user for input. How can I test this? For example:

1. start ./prog
2. prog asks: Username:
3. Check/assert that the string is the expected string (string should be accessible to shunit2)
4. Now I need to specify an input, say John
5. prog prints something in response, say it echoes John
6. Check/assert that John is the expected output (string should be again accessible to shunit2)

How do I assert/verify/check this in shunit2, i.e. that the given input John results in the correct output string John?

I know there exist tools like 'expect' or 'expect-lite'. But, how would I test this using the shell only?

Or, how can I integrate expect or expect-lite so that I can verify the input using shunit2?

Comment: You wouldn't. Because you can't. Use expect.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to pass the input to prog's stdin. Among many ways to do that is this:

```
{ echo "Username"; echo "John"; } | ./prog
```